# Packing squares 1 to 38 in a size 138 square

Tags: recreational-mathematics, packing-problem, open-problem, oeis

For 40 years, it's been an unsolved question whether squares of size 1 to 38 can fit in a size 138 square. It's the lowest unresolved value in [sequence A005842](https://oeis.org/A005842) Here's a packing where squares 10 to 38 are placed.

[image: 38 squares]

Is it possible to place squares 9 to 38 without overlap?  Could 8 be added to that? Can all the squares be placed?  This looks like a resolvable problem.

[Sequence A0081287](https://oeis.org/A081287), packing sequential squares in the smallest possible rectangle, is unsolved above 32 squares.

Comment: Another interesting OEIS sequence: the least k such that squares of size k through n fit in a square of size A005842(n) - 1.